# SQL to retrieve results just between two users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, laravel

I need to retrieve talks between two users, but I don't know how... my results have unwanted talks, my current sql:

```
select *
from user_talk t1
inner join user_talk t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where
    t1.talk_id = t2.talk_id and
    (
        t1.user_id = 1 or
        t2.user_id = 4
    );
```

This sql show results between users 1 and 4 but too between user 1 and user 2, and user 2 and 65, but I want just user 1 and 4.

How to write the correct sql?

**EDIT: user_talks**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reverse`.`user_talk` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `talk_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INVITED',
  `status` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_usertalk_1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_usertalk_2_idx` (`talk_id` ASC),
  INDEX `user_in_talk_idx` (`talk_id` ASC, `user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usertalk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `reverse`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usertalk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`talk_id`)
    REFERENCES `reverse`.`talk` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**talk**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reverse`.`talk` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**message**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reverse`.`message` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `talk_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `body` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNREAD',
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_message_1_idx` (`sender_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_message_2_idx` (`receiver_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_message_3_idx` (`talk_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`)
    REFERENCES `reverse`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`receiver_id`)
    REFERENCES `reverse`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`talk_id`)
    REFERENCES `reverse`.`talk` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Describe your schema. Do you need only talks or user data too ?

Comment: @FLefèvre see the table sql. For now just the user_talks data. Thanks!

Comment: Describe also your `talk` table. But I think my answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select user_talks from user 1 to user 4 and from user 4 to user 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_talk t1
INNER JOIN user_talk t2 ON t1.talk_id = t2.talk_id
WHERE 
    (t1.user_id = 1 AND t2.user_id = 4)
    OR
    (t1.user_id = 4 AND t2.user_id = 1)
```

I explain:

- You need to select user_talk from 2 users so I select from 2 tables.
- You need to select conversations so I guess talk_id should be the same.
- You need them from user 1 to 4 or from user 4 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

(Please try this

```
select *
  from user_talk t1
       inner join user_talk t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 where (t1.user_id = 1 or t1.user_id = 4)
   and (t2.user_id = 1 or t2.user_id = 4);
```

**UPDATE** : just ran this SQL for the data shown below

[image]

and got this reult, only for `user_id` 1 & 4

[image]

Comment: The sql results are the same that in my sql, in my answer.